# Powershell - create CSV of users with CRM licences who haven't logged in for more than 30 days

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm trying to combine the output from two commandlets. I need to list all the users with a particular licence SKUID (CRMPLAN) who haven't logged in for over 30 days.

Is something along these lines even close?

```
$UserList = get-MSOLUser -All | where {$_.isLicensed -eq "TRUE" -and $_.Licenses.AccountSKUID -eq "Domain:CRMPLAN"}

$MasterList = @()
foreach ($DisplayName in $UserList) {
$MyObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
LastLogonTime = (Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 30.00:00:00 | where {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'} | FT Name,ObjectClass –A}).LastLogonTime
}  
$MasterList += $MyObject
}
$MasterList | select displayname,IsLicenced,LastLogonTime - export-CSV C:\LastLogonDate.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so right now your basically getting a list of users in $userList and then getting a list of ALL of the last logon times of users who have not logged in within the last 30 days for each of them and adding it to an array, then trying to do some selects on data that is not there since your only selecting the lastlogontime, which does not actually exist in AD.  What you need to do instead is loop through them and check their *lastlogondate* to see if they have logged in within the last 30 days and then add their info to the array if they have not(you can also do this by collecting both arrays and then processing using group-object but that's a lot more tricky).  You also have to remember that if the property you are selecting is not part of the object you are working with in the pipeline you will need to use an expression in your select to stuff it into the object

So your foreach loop would look something like this.

```
$masterList = @()

foreach($user in $userList){
    $oldDate = (get-date).AddDays(-30)
    $userObj = Get-ADUser -Identity $user.UserPrincipalName -Properties lastlogondate | Select-Object displayname,LastLogonDate,@{Name="IsLicensed"; Expression={$user.isLicensed}}

    if($userObj.lastLogonDate -le $oldDate){
        $masterList += $userObj
    }
}
```

Finally make sure that when you do your export to use a pipe rather than a subtraction symbol.  so your last line should look like 
    $masterlist | export-csv c:\tmp\lastlogondate.csv

Note that there is no need to do the select here since we have already done a select to get the data we need inside of the loop, also try to avoid placing files on the root of C:\, any machine with UAC enabled will throw permissions errors when trying to do that unless you are running as an admin, which is unneeded for this script.  Hope this helps and please let me know if you have any questions.